# Google Charts - Centralizar valor no gráfico 'Donut Chart'

Tags: javascript, google-charts

Estou com um problema no google charts mais especificamente no gráfico `Donut Chart`, o valor so fica centralizado quando esta em 100%, quando esta abaixo disso o gráfico fica `deformado, vide imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  // Draw evolucao 1 chart
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawevolucao1Chart);
    // Draw evolucao 2 chart
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawevolucao2Chart);


    // Chart 1 ==========

    function drawevolucao1Chart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Metas', 'Porcentagens'],
        ['',     .01],
        ['',     .01]
        ]);

      var options = {
        pieHole: 0.7,
        pieSliceTextStyle: {
          color: 'black'
        },
        slices: {
          0: { color: '#2592c9' },
          1: { color: 'transparent' }
        },
        backgroundColor: {
          backgroundColor: {
            stroke: 'transparent',
            strokeWidth: 0
          }
        },
        tooltip: { trigger: 'none' },
        pieSliceText: 'percentage',
        pieSliceTextStyle:{color: '#767474', fontName: '<global-font-name>', fontSize: '<global-font-size>'},
        legend: 'none',
        width: '550px',
        height: '600px',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        fontSize:20,
        chartArea:{left:0,top:7,width:'100%',height:'90%'}
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart-evolucao-fundamenta-1'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    // Chart 2 ==========

    function drawevolucao2Chart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Metas', 'Porcentagens'],
        ['',     .1],
        ['',     .00]
        ]);

      var options = {
        pieHole: 0.7,
        pieSliceTextStyle: {
          color: 'black'
        },
        slices: {
          0: { color: '#2592c9' },
          1: { color: 'transparent' }
        },
        backgroundColor: {
          backgroundColor: {
            stroke: 'transparent',
            strokeWidth: 0
          }
        },
        tooltip: { trigger: 'none' },
        pieSliceText: 'percentage',
        pieSliceTextStyle:{color: '#767474', fontName: '<global-font-name>', fontSize: '<global-font-size>'},
        legend: 'none',
        width: '550px',
        height: '600px',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        fontSize:20,
        chartArea:{left:0,top:7,width:'100%',height:'90%'}
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart-evolucao-fundamenta-2'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
});
```

```css
#sidebar
{
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
}
.sidebar-chart-1
{
  padding: 25px 10px;
  background-color: #efeeee;
}
.sidebar-chart-1 h3
{
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #4c4b4b;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.sidebar h3 .icon-info
{
  color: #42abf4;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -2px;
  top: -3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover
  {
    opacity: .9;
  }
}
.sidebar h3 .tooltip-info
{
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #42abf4;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: -55px;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;

  display: none;
}
.sidebar h3 .tooltip-info:before
{
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 11px;
  bottom: -5px;


  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #42abf4;
}
.form-acumulado
{
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
.form-acumulado input
{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.form-acumulado .salvar-dados
{
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  &:hover
  {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
}
.form-acumulado .form-group
{
  margin: 0;
}
small
{
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #767474;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

  // --- evolução fundamental 1 e 2 #####

.container-evolucao,
.container-distribuicao
{
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #efeeee;
  padding: 15px;
}
.container-evolucao h3,
.container-distribuicao h3
{
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #4c4b4b;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.container-evolucao h4,
.container-distribuicao h4
{
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #42abf4;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API library and the piechart library.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
     // ... draw the chart...
</script>

<section id="new-charts">
<aside id="sidebar" class="sidebar col-sx-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
 

  <!-- Charts Evolution  -->

  <div class="evolucao-fundamental-1 container-evolucao sidebar">
    <h3>Evolução da Meta - Fundamental I</h3>
    <div id="chart-evolucao-fundamenta-1"></div>
    <h4>META ALCANÇADA</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="evolucao-fundamental-2 container-evolucao sidebar">
    <h3>Evolução da Meta - Fundamental I</h3>
    <div id="chart-evolucao-fundamenta-2"></div>
    <h4>META ALCANÇADA</h4>
  </div>

</aside>
<!-- FIM ASIDE CHARTS  -->
</section>
```

**Atualizado:**

Preciso que o numero fique centralizado igual o 100%

Comment: Olá Eric, poste os `options` do chart também, assim ficará mais fácil lhe ajudar

Comment: Não consegui rodar o snippet, aparentemente parece um erro de CSS, pode ser que algum outro CSS do teu código está afetando o gráfico. Tem como corrigir o snippet para ver como fica em ambiente isolado?

Comment: @Randrade Ta la atualizado ... Obrigado.

Comment: Isso não é um problema do Google Charts. Vc é que está tentando usar de uma forma diferente da especificada [na documentação](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart). O que acontece é que mesmo configurado como "PieHole", esse gráfico ainda é um gráfico de "pizza". Dessa forma, o rótulo é colocado o mais próximo possível do centro **da fatia** (no seu primeiro exemplo, os 90.9% são da maior fatia, transparente). Por isso que só quando tem 100% (uma só fatia, englobando todo o gráfico) o rótulo fica no centro.

Comment: Eu imagino que uma solução seja você mesmo desenhar o texto do rótulo central. No SOEN tem uma possível abordagem que pode ser útil: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256527/display-total-in-center-of-donut-pie-chart-using-google-charts

Comment: @LuizVieira poutz esse google charts eh legal mas eh mto engessado rsrs  Vou dar uma olhada ve se acho alguma solução pq parece `simples` mas não eh rs obrigado

Comment: @Erick, caso não consiga utilizar o Google Charts.. dê uma olhada no [HighchartsJS](http://www.highcharts.com/demo).

Comment: @DouglasGarrido foda que o trampo ta finalizado ja eh so uns ajustes, mas vou tentar criar um span dentro da div que coloco o grafico ai eu centralizo a span e via backend eu alimento ela com o valor (%) do grafico, eh uma gambiarra mas to achando que o "melhor" jeito.  obrigado.